# Detect record changes in Azure Mobile App Client

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

What combination of StoreTrackingOptions and StoreChangeEvent do I have to use to detect changes in local records resulting from any Pull operation?

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly about your requirements. Do you mean you want to get the changes in client when the mobile app service side data changed? Have you write any codes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by implementing a tracker that tracks last updated timestamp on each of the local sync tables.  When changes are synced from the server (Pull), for each table in question, I query the latest timestamp and compare it to the one I am tracking.  If the timestamp is newer, I update my tracked timestamp and know that the table has new/updated data.

Now, I coupled this with a "scheduled" sync executed on a back thread (never-ending loop with await.Delay()).  I am using MvvmCross and if a sync table has newer records (as per above description), I publish a message on Messenger to that effect.  Whoever subscribes to the message, can update their UI, however they see fit.

So far this model works really good because front-end updates are not coupled to back-end syncs and back-end syncs that bring new data can update the UI without a need for an explicit check for new data.  Kind of loosely coupled setup.